# Dyanmic array name

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how I can amend part of the array name dynamically within a `foreach`.

I have a variable `$i` which is increased on each loop. Within the loop, I want to change `X` of `['new_row_X']` to whatever the `$i` is equal to. So for example:

```
$i = '10';

foreach( $order->items as $item ) {

    $data['field_id_185']['rows']['new_row_10']['col_id_25'] = 'Entry ID';

    $i++

}
```

OR

```
$i = '5';

foreach( $order->items as $item ) {

    $data['field_id_185']['rows']['new_row_5']['col_id_25'] = 'Entry ID';

    $i++

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just concatenate the index:

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($order -> items as $item) {
    $data['field_id_185']['row']['new_row_'.$i]['col_id_25'] = 'Entry ID';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = '10';

foreach( $order->items as $item ) {
    foreach($data['field_id_185']['rows'] as $key=>$value) {
        if (preg_match('/^new_row_.+$/', $key)) {
            $data['field_id_185']['rows']["new_row_$ii"] = $value;
            unset($data['field_id_185']['rows'][$key]);
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
```